# Can I maintain separate scale sizes for the iPhone and iPad simulators?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I like keeping my iPad simulator at 75% scale, and iPhone at 100%.

Can I have those settings remembered and applied automatically when building to those simulators? Preferably globally, across any project, etc.

Comment: Interesting question. It has nothing to do with the code or Xcode and I know what you mean but if it's not in a sort of simulator preferences or some hidden preference file then the answer is no and apple just didn't make it remember those settings once simulator gets closed out.

Comment: Maybe you could do something with AppleScript. If you can find a way to determine if the simulator is displaying the ipad or iphone you can  then click the appropriate menu item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry.
But command + 1, command + 2, command + 3 are handy shortcuts!